# Microsoft Access - Duplicate record issue

Tags: ms-access, primary-key, duplicates

I have an issue in Microsft Access where I have a table detailing the amount of money paid to a client identifier for a particular month. The table has not been set up with a primary key so the table contains one record for each payment made rather than one record for each individual that includes every payment.

See the link for a clearer picture.

[image: http://imgur.com/HlP6Mfk]

The top table on the image I have linked  is an example of what I have now and the bottom table is what I am hoping to achieve.

Can anybody advise me on the best way to achieve what I'm looking for? I'd be grateful if anybody could direct me to somewhere that could teach me as I have never used Access before and I'm keen to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that the top image is setup correctly for a database.  If there would only be a single payment per month, then you could make the first two columns a composite key...otherwise, all three columns would be the composite key.  You wouldn't want to have to go back in every single month and create new columns for that month and the total payment.  Your database would be growing in the wrong direction.

If you were wanting to use the bottom image, I would think Excel would be fine.

Also...I don't see any duplicate records.  Having multiple rows with the same ID is pretty much what you want in this case.